Ubuntu installation is unable to boot, I am stuck at the GRUB CLI everytime I try to restart
I have a laptop with Ubuntu installed as the only OS, I've been using it fine for months.
Today, it stopped working. I think it may have been that I turned it off on accident when the grub menu was loading, but I'm not sure if that caused it.  Whenever I try to turn on the computer, the GRUB CLI loads but I'm unable to get it to boot.
exit command just restarts the loop and I end up back in the GRUB CLI.
boot command says I need to load the kernel first.
grub> ls
(proc) (memdisk) (hd0) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)

the filesystem for (hd0,gpt1) is
/
    /efi
        /boot
            some .efi files
        /ubuntu
            some .efi files, a bootx64.csv, /fw, and a grub.cfg file

otherwise there seem to be no files grub can see in any of the other partitions
If I set prefix=(hd0,gpt1)/efi/ubuntu, then insmod linux then insmod normal then normal, it says "no such device [long string]"
It's an encrypted hard drive.  I used a live usb to "try" ubuntu, and ran boot-repair after I used cryptsetup open to decrypt nvme0n1p3.
Here's the output from running lsblk on the live usb:
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                         7:0    0   1.6G  1 loop  /rofs
loop1                         7:1    0   471M  1 loop  
loop2                         7:2    0 874.4M  1 loop  
loop3                         7:3    0  74.3M  1 loop  /snap/core22/1564
loop4                         7:4    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
loop5                         7:5    0  10.7M  1 loop  /snap/firmware-updater/127
loop6                         7:6    0 269.8M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/4793
loop7                         7:7    0 505.1M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop8                         7:8    0  10.5M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/1173
loop9                         7:9    0  91.7M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop10                        7:10   0  38.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/21759
loop11                        7:11   0   500K  1 loop  /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/178
loop12                        7:12   0 116.8M  1 loop  /snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237
loop13                        7:13   0 149.6M  1 loop  /snap/thunderbird/507
sda                           8:0    1  14.4G  0 disk  
├─sda1                        8:1    1   5.8G  0 part  /cdrom
├─sda2                        8:2    1     5M  0 part  
├─sda3                        8:3    1   300K  0 part  
└─sda4                        8:4    1   8.7G  0 part  /var/crash
                                                       /var/log
nvme0n1                     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1                 259:4    0     1G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p2                 259:5    0     2G  0 part  
└─nvme0n1p3                 259:6    0 235.4G  0 part  
  └─ccc                     252:0    0 235.4G  0 crypt 
    └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 252:1    0 235.4G  0 lvm 

Here's the output from boot-repair:
boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20241111_2208]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/fwupdx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       crypto_LUKS
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: N3MET22W (1.21 )(1.21) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 001F
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0003,0000,0010,0011,0012,0013,0014,0015,0016,0017,0018,0019,001C,001D,001E,001F,0020,0021,0022,0023,0024,0002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,2818748c-f04b-4fc8-a0a3-300afad723e5,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000035000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0001* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,2818748c-f04b-4fc8-a0a3-300afad723e5,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0002* Linux-Firmware-Updater    HD(1,GPT,2818748c-f04b-4fc8-a0a3-300afad723e5,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\fwupdx64.efi)
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,14e74811-f833-4b4b-8e94-a8bae1a58f94,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014  Asset Information FvFile(da465b87-a26f-4c12-b78a-0361428fa026)
Boot0015  Regulatory Information    FvFile(478c92a0-2622-42b7-a65d-5894169e4d24)
Boot0016  ThinkShield secure wipe   FvFile(3593a0d5-bd52-43a0-808e-cbff5ece2477)
Boot0017  ThinkShield Passwordless Power-On Device Manager  FvFile(08448b41-7f83-49be-82a7-0e84790ab133)
Boot0018  Wi-Fi Configuration   FvFile(d3aaff0f-cb22-4792-896c-802c2e9383ba)2d004100700070000000
Boot0019  Intel(R) MEBx FvFile(29a70110-7762-4211-ae88-fab19b7665be)
Boot001A  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot001B  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot001C* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot001D* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot001E* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot001F* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot0020* PXE BOOT  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot0021* LENOVO CLOUD  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,ad38ccbbf7edf04d959cf42aa74d3650)/Uri(https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/cdeploy/efi/boot.efi)
Boot0022* ON-PREMISE    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,ad38ccbbf7edf04d959cf42aa74d3650)/Uri()
Boot0023  Other CD  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,aea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a35400)
Boot0024  Other HDD VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,ca88c2349e7ae947beeb43038a5aeae700)
Boot0025* IDER BOOT CDROM   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(11,1)
Boot0026* IDER BOOT Floppy  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(11,0)
Boot0027* ATA HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f6)
Boot0028* ATAPI CD  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,aea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a354)

39bc76ff6662f4fbe9aa116e4c997b41   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
4ba5a5aad43c197e9fb58b76b404d287   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
258e2247878acb0a2944052e26657e81   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/fwupdx64.efi
66f69798ad23240e43b7ba0044a914c4   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4ba5a5aad43c197e9fb58b76b404d287   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p2   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, 

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p2   : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk identifier: BC00A794-172F-47E9-8E03-DB602ACB1BCB
           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1    2048   2203647   2201600     1G EFI System
nvme0n1p2 2203648   6397951   4194304     2G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p3 6397952 500115455 493717504 235.4G Linux filesystem
Disk sda: 14.44 GiB, 15506341888 bytes, 30285824 sectors
Disk identifier: EED3DE8A-ACD3-4541-BA15-9014C007D874
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sda1        64 12105119 12105056  5.8G Microsoft basic data
sda2  12105120 12115263    10144    5M EFI System
sda3  12115264 12115863      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sda4  12115968 30283775 18167808  8.7G Linux filesystem
Disk mapper/ccc: 235.41 GiB, 252766584832 bytes, 493684736 sectors
Disk mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 235.41 GiB, 252765536256 bytes, 493682688 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:15.5GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:PNY USB 2.0 FD:;
1:32.8kB:6198MB:6198MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:6198MB:6203MB:5194kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:6203MB:6203MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:6203MB:15.5GB:9302MB:ext4::;
mapper/ccc:253GB:dm:512:512:unknown:Linux device-mapper (crypt):;
mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv:253GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:253GB:253GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:256GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:SKHynix_HFS256GDE9X081N:;
1:1049kB:1128MB:1127MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:1128MB:3276MB:2147MB:::;
3:3276MB:256GB:253GB:::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME                        FSTYPE      UUID                                   PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                         iso9660     2024-08-27-16-23-26-00                                                      Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sda1                      iso9660     2024-08-27-16-23-26-00                 eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba14-9014c007d874 Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sda2                      vfat        3C53-CAEB                              eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba17-9014c007d874 ESP                      Appended2
├─sda3                                                                         eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba16-9014c007d874                          Gap1
└─sda4                      ext4        10370da4-88ae-4d81-87f9-a21c0c289284   f104bb5c-6652-48c6-ac62-80e7e90f99e7 writable                 
nvme0n1                                                                                                                                      
├─nvme0n1p1                 vfat        AC58-0E43                              2818748c-f04b-4fc8-a0a3-300afad723e5                          
├─nvme0n1p2                                                                    d5781fb0-76e2-4e3f-aac0-0d8399a42bec                          
└─nvme0n1p3                 crypto_LUKS a2ac37e9-591e-4bc9-8623-a865644092f4   49ea5b3e-5e71-418b-a2d2-4b8fce1ce7cf                          
  └─ccc                     LVM2_member dWJBu1-uYJg-SRDp-cWdJ-bmHv-xVdU-pE4P0j                                                               
    └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4        c39e2bb8-f753-4c9d-bbd8-dfa60a48dcd6                                                                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                                    1G   1% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/sda1                                                          0 100% /cdrom
efivarfs                                                      123.2K  35% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1                                                vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
ccc
control
ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid b840fc96-a180-49a0-b4c0-3968bbfcd75a root 
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on nvme0n1p2

Unknown BootLoader on nvme0n1p3


================================= User choice ==================================

Is there RAID on this computer? no


==================== blkid (filtered) before lvm activation ====================

/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="AC58-0E43" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="2818748c-f04b-4fc8-a0a3-300afad723e5"
/dev/sda1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2024-08-27-16-23-26-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PARTLABEL="ISO9660" PARTUUID="eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba14-9014c007d874"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="a2ac37e9-591e-4bc9-8623-a865644092f4" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="49ea5b3e-5e71-418b-a2d2-4b8fce1ce7cf"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="writable" UUID="10370da4-88ae-4d81-87f9-a21c0c289284" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f104bb5c-6652-48c6-ac62-80e7e90f99e7"
/dev/sda2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="3C53-CAEB" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Appended2" PARTUUID="eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba17-9014c007d874"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: UUID="c39e2bb8-f753-4c9d-bbd8-dfa60a48dcd6" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ccc: UUID="dWJBu1-uYJg-SRDp-cWdJ-bmHv-xVdU-pE4P0j" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTUUID="d5781fb0-76e2-4e3f-aac0-0d8399a42bec"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Gap1" PARTUUID="eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba16-9014c007d874"


================================ LVM activation ================================

modprobe dm-mod  
vgscan --mknodes
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
vgchange -ay
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv' [<235.41 GiB] inherit
blkid -g



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

You may want to retry after mounting your encrypted partitions so that the tool can verify their contents. (cryptsetup open)
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

How do I load the kernal so I can fix my ubuntu installation without losing all my files?

It looks like you're working with a LUKS encrypted installation, are you?  If so, you might have a broken crypt setup entirely.

I was able to use cryptsetup open to successfully mount the encrypted partition when I booted from a live USB. Would this indicate that the crypt setup is working properly?

the output says you don't have a bootloader, so if you just installed you have no bootloader installed.  You would probably have to install GRUB.  If you have the Live USB, you can attempt to use sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1 to attempt to reinstall the boot loader.  But worst case you'll have to backup your data from your encrypted partitions to external media, reinstall, and then reload your data after the reinstall.  Fixing encrypted installs and boots can be difficult.

I updated the question to reflect that I did not just install Ubuntu, I've been using it fine for months.  I'll try the grub-install, appreciate the suggestion

sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p3 results in "cannot find EFI directory"

Don't install grub on the partition. Install it on the drive. So run sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1 instead of sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p3. Then run sudo update-grub to recreate grub.cfg.

This and this might help

@ben432rew You'll note I did NOT say to use a specific partition, I said to use the base drive. Use my command verbatim exactly as I wrote it, like mpboden echoed.

Thank you, I now see that you did indicate /nvme0n1, however, sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1 also results in the "cannot find EFI directory"

Did you mount the EFI partition as well as your root? Are you doing this within a chroot? Take a look at the links I listed.

I did mount both the EFI partition as well as root after I decrypted it. I did it within chroot.  Everything was successful, but restarting the computer I still ended up at the grub cli and it says I need to load the kernel still

After doing all that, did you run sudo update-grub? This updates your grub.cfg file.

I did, tried a number of times with minor variations between the two answers you posted but always did the update-grub

If you can mount your encrypted partition from live installer, first thing you need to do is make a good backup. If issues with ESP, you may need dosfsck. sudo fsck.vfat -t -a /dev/nvme0n1p1  Then with Boot-Repair, decrypt LVM and see it it can update grub or use advanced mode to totally reinstall grub.
